# CORS policy ERROR with local PHP and React TSX App

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm new to PHP and React TSX, and using `XAMPP`. I'm trying to send an `axios` POST request to my local `apache` server along with credentials so I can use `$_SESSION` data. I have been trying a lot even with lots of online research, but I still can't fix my `CORS policy ERROR`. Below I have given my code and would like any help fixing it. Thanks

`home.tsx`

```
axios.request({
    url: "http://localhost/content.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: d,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        mode: "cors"
    }
}).then(res => {
    // CODE
}).catch(err => {
    // CODE
});
```

`content.php`

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header("Content-type: application/json, text/plain");
    
    // Code
?>
```

`error`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/content.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Comment: You can solve this problem by using Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 extension for Chrome. follow this link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en .

Comment: You can set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) then fetch from `/content.php`

Comment: @OktamYaqubov I have enabled the extension but I'm still getting the error. Do I have to do some sort of setup for it to work? Also, I'm using the extension on Microsoft Edge Chromium.

Comment: I've testet it both of them. And it works fine. I think you need configure this extention for you.